# why sort not work for vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Here is my code:

```
vector<EntryMsg> entryMsgs; // i store some Entry Msg in this vector

void step5(vector<EntryMsg> entryMsg)
{
    sort(entryMsg.begin(), entryMsg.end(), [](const EntryMsg& a, const EntryMsg& b) { 
        return (a.fields.instrument[0] <= b.fields.instrument[0]) || (a.fields.instrument[1] <= b.fields.instrument[1]) || (a.fields.instrument[2] <= b.fields.instrument[2]);
    });
    for_each(entryMsg.begin(), entryMsg.end(), [](const EntryMsg& msg){
        cout<<msg.fields.instrument[0]<<msg.fields.instrument[1]<<msg.fields.instrument[2]<<endl;
    });
}
```

i call it using: `step5(entryMsgs);`

But from the output, i find the `entryMsgs` is not sorted, what's the reason?

Answer (score 2):

The reason's your broken logic...

```
return (a.fields.instrument[0] <= b.fields.instrument[0]) || (a.fields.instrument[1] <= b.fields.instrument[1]) || (a.fields.instrument[2] <= b.fields.instrument[2])
```

For example, if `a.fields.instrument[1] <= b.fields.instrument[1]` you return true to say `a` < `b`, but `a.field.instrument[0]` might be greater than `b`'s.

I could tell you how to fix it, but have a think yourself, and try a couple examples on paper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `vector` as **reference**:

```
void step5(vector<EntryMsg>& entryMsg)
{
    sort(entryMsg.begin(), entryMsg.end(), [](const EntryMsg& a, const EntryMsg& b) { 
        return (a.fields.instrument[0] <= b.fields.instrument[0]) || (a.fields.instrument[1] <= b.fields.instrument[1]) || (a.fields.instrument[2] <= b.fields.instrument[2]);
    });
    for_each(entryMsg.begin(), entryMsg.end(), [](const EntryMsg& msg){
        cout<<msg.fields.instrument[0]<<msg.fields.instrument[1]<<msg.fields.instrument[2]<<endl;
    });
}
```

Such large objects should always be passed as reference, or as `const` reference if called function doesn't modify it. Ideally never as copy.